# PHP How listen ip and port

Tags: php

We are have script:

```
<?php
//test
echo 'hello';
?>
```

Server send query on 5.82.222.16:2054.

How return script if query was send on 5.82.222.16:2054

How we can make it?

P.S.: we would like return script if query was send only on ip 5.82.222.16 and port 2054 ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @sgtBOSE for little projects we check `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`, but for it example we thinks that need use sockets

Comment: @sgtBOSE but we have not used it before and we do not know how to attach script to IP.

Comment: "Server send query" - excuse me, server or client sent the query? Why don't you want to setup Apache to listed to port 2054? It will be really hard for you to implement the certain protocol and use low level sockets.

Comment: @user4035 other server send query. I have not worked with this before. ask please if need other answers for help me.

Comment: @Brown If you want to implement it on low level, here is the info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: @user4035 what is low level ?

Comment: @Brown It means, that you'll have to implement a protocol of communication. Which is already implemented by Apache for you.